# what's the easiest way to upgrade Gitlab from 8.0 to latest version?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have a Gitlab 8.0 server(25 projects, 10 users, 30+ ssh keys), I want upgrade to newest version, but seems no easy way to do this.

Following the upgrade guide, I have to upgrade step by step, means I may need 10+ hours to do this. :(

Can any one teach me what's the easiest way to upgrade to last version ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the exact same migration, and... I had to script it.

That is because I needed to upgrade to 9.0, 9.1,9.2...10.0, 10.1, ...,11.0, ... to finally 11.5.

So if you do an upgrade from 8.0 to 8.1 manually once, you can see the steps (mainly stop, upgrade, check the configuration and start) and script them in order to repeat the process easily.